# Error when declaring local array

Tags: c++, arrays

Something like this throws an error:

```
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int test[1000000] = {};
}
```

Something like this doesn't:

```
using namespace std;

int test[1000000] = {};

int main()
{
}
```

Why is that? A million ints isn't even too memory-demanding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first one allocates space on the stack.  The second one allocates space in the data segment at compile/link time.  The stack is of limited size.

Answer (score 0):

Stack is not dynamic, but you can also do this

> ```
> int* arr = new int[1000000];
> ```

but don't forget to delete it because this declares array in the heap which is dynamic memory and by deleting it from heap you prevent the memory leak.

Example :

> ```
> delete arr;
> ```

This is just alternative how to use memory

Comment: That's quite beside the question.

Comment: @Deduplicator I disagree. This allocates the array from the heap instead of the stack, which solves OP's error.

Comment: @DavidLively Which is exactly why it's besides the point. The question isn't "How do I fix it", but rather "Why does this happen." This in *no way at all* explains why the stack allocation fails.